# Specifying project name in msdeploy

Tags: msbuild, command-line-arguments, msdeploy

I've got two web projects in one solution, and I'd like to deploy them both using msbuild and WebDeploy (this happens through a CI server).

Currently, I'm running a command line:

```
C:\ProjectFolder>msbuild <solution>.sln
    /p:Configuration=<Release>
    /p:OutputPath=bin
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True
    /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
    /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<ServerUrl:port>/msdeploy.axd
    /p:username=<user>
    /p:password=<password>
    /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=<SiteName>
    /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

This deploys one project, as expected. But how can I deploy the other as well? There's nowhere in this command line where I specified a project name - why did it choose one project to deploy over the other?

Ideally, I'd be able to deploy two project with the same command, something like

```
...

    /p:Project=Project1
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=<SiteName>/Project1
    /p:Project=Project2
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=<SiteName>/Project2
```

But I doubt that's possible. Alternatively, I just want to know how to specify a project name in the command line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it would be better to divide the single call to three:
 - Build sln;
 - Deploy site1;
 - Deploy site2;

```
msbuild.exe <solution>.sln
    /p:Configuration=<Release>
    /p:OutputPath=bin

msbuild.exe project1dir\proj1.csproj
    /p:Configuration=<Release>
    /p:OutputPath=<Path to common bin>
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True
    /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
    /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<ServerUrl:port>/msdeploy.axd
    /p:username=<user>
    /p:password=<password>
    /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=<SiteName>/Project1
    /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC

msbuild.exe project1dir\proj2.csproj
    /p:Configuration=<Release>
    /p:OutputPath=<Path to common bin>
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True
    /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
    /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<ServerUrl:port>/msdeploy.axd
    /p:username=<user>
    /p:password=<password>
    /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=<SiteName>/Project2
    /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

Comment: Right. The part I was missing was actually calling msbuild with the project name instead of the solution - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command line from the projects' root folder(s), and don't specify a file to build, msbuild should automatically select the project in that folder.

This will require two separate command line calls, tho.

You can then build on this by building a batch file that cd's to each of the folders in turn and runs msbuild separately, or equally build your own proj file for msbuild that triggers each build.

Sorry I can't craft an example at the moment tho-on a phone!